# Responsive wordpress site using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a blog redesign and I am well acquainted with responsive design. I am not so familiar with wordpress though, so I am thinking of using twitter bootstrap. My question is, if I customize my stylesheets and other files(like header.php etc) can a bootstrap update erase all my changes? What would be the bets way to keep bootstrap as a base and building from there? I have my design specs from a designer, so I have to customize or build from scratch.

Comment: Unless your client must update their own website using a CMS like word  press just start from scratch and use Bootstrap. WordPress is restrictive and cumbersome and painful to update, I've grown to hate it!

Comment: Thanks. I am using Bootstrap, but my clients need to update website using wordpress. I don't building from scratch but the template i found(the bootstrap) I am thinking of working on it and modify code as per my design. Now are there any bootstrap updates that might hurt me in future?

Comment: Then I would recommend a bootstrap theme for word press if your designer specs don't work with these templates you're in for a challenge!  http://wptavern.com/18-free-wordpress-themes-built-with-bootstrap